# How to delete UIImageView with associate tag and ids

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, sqlite, uiimageview

I have UIImageView associated with object_sku. Images are displaying scrollview for clickable UIButton. When i click it goes to center of the screen and displays like tag 0,1,2,3. Tag 0 image contain object_sku 123, Tag 1 contain object_sku test, Tag 2 contain object_sku test1. The UIImageView images displays in the screen order of first image click tag0 and tag1, tag2. If i delete Tag0 image, it getting NSLog of Tag object_sku (test1). Why it's not getting Tag0 object_sku. It's getting last update value from the screen. How to solve this? I have to get, if i delete Tag0 image i should get object_sku 123. But i didn't get.

Images in the center of the screen from array:

```
         mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,350,199)];


         [mmageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

         //  [mmageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]]]]];


         [mmageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1]] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {



         }];


         [mmageView setTag:[sender tag]-1];

         NSLog(@"mmageView  Tag: %i",mmageView.tag);


         object = [[ObjectAddedToScreen alloc] init];
         object.productDescription = [descript_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
         object.view = mmageView;
         object.productId=[product_id_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];
         object.object_sku=[sku_array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]-1];


   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


         NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
         NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


         if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



           //  const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT tag FROM product_sku where tag = '%ld'",(long)object.object_imageView.tag] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


             const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into product_sku (sku, tag) values ('%@', '%ld')", object.object_sku, (long)mmageView.tag] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];




             NSLog(@"sql is %s",sqlInsert);

           // BOOL favExist = false;

             sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

             if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                 // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                 while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                  //   favExist = true;

                     const char *sqlInsert = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into product_sku (sku, tag) values ('%@', '%ld')", object.object_sku, (long)mmageView.tag] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                     //----

                     NSLog(@"sql insert is %s",sqlInsert);


                     // [catID release];

                     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlInsert, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                     NSLog(@"error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                     if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



                 }
             }





         NSLog(@"mmageView object.object_sku is %@", object.object_sku);

         [self.objectsAddedToScreen addObject:object];

         [self.view addSubview:mmageView];
```

Delete the images:

```
    int new_delete_tag;

    NSString *sku_delete;



    NSArray *subViewsArray = self.view.subviews;
    CGPoint tapLocation1 = [sender locationInView: self.view];

    for(UIView *v in subViewsArray){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)v;{
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, tapLocation1)){

                    [imageView removeFromSuperview];


                    for (object in self.objectsAddedToScreen)


                        if (object.view == sender.view)
                        {
                          //  NSString *productDescription = object.productDescription;

                                        //  txtt.text=productDescription;

                              UIImageView *imageView = object.object_imageView;

                             NSInteger object_sku = sender.view.tag;


                        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


                    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db1.sqlite"];
                  //  NSLog(@"filepath %@",path);


                    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {



                        const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT sku,tag FROM product_sku where tag = '%d'",object_sku] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


                        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

                      //  BOOL favExist = false;

                        sqlite3_stmt *statement, *addStmt;

                        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                                sku_delete = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                                 NSLog(@"sku_delete is %@",sku_delete);

                              //  favExist = true;

                                 new_delete_tag = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);

                                 NSLog(@"new_delete_tag is %d",new_delete_tag);

                              //  if(new_delete_tag && sku_delete){


                                    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

                                    const char *sqlDelete = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete FROM product_sku where sku = '%@' AND tag = '%d'",sku_delete,new_delete_tag] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



                                    NSLog(@"sql delete is %s",sqlDelete);

                                    //  NSLog(@"sql delete1 is %s",sqlDelete1);

                                    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlDelete, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting tag from product_sku  . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                                    NSLog(@"%s error finalizing %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                                    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
                                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting tag from product_sku . '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


                              //  }



                            }
                        }

                     }

                        }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question at hand, re your SQLite code, if you call `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, you should call `sqlite3_finalize` when you're done iterating through your result set, or else you'll leak. Also, you should be checking the results of your SQLite calls, and if any of them fail to return ’SQLITE_OK` (except `sqlite3_step` which should return either `SQLITE_ROW` or `SQLITE_DONE`), log `sqlite3_errmsg`. Right now, if you have any SQL errors, you have no way of knowing.

Comment: I don't have any SQL error

Comment: OK. In the spirit of defensive programming, I just always log error if prepare failed and a few of yours don't. Not a big deal, though. But definitely add the `sqlite3_finalize` calls.

Comment: When i use delete it's deleting the value from database. But the problem is it taking last updated cat_id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delete routine, you are iterating through the images to see which to remove, but you then proceed to use `object.object_sku` (which doesn't appear to bear any relation to the image you tapped in). I would have assumed that you were going to use the `tag` of the image view in order to know which underlying object you were deleting.

Comment: if i'm clicking cat_id=1 images and it displays the screen.. and click cat_id=2 images it displays to screen..Then delete the tag value of 0 in cat_id=1 it deleting cat_id=2 value..Maybe because of last update value from cat_id

Comment: I used mvc ObjectAddedToScreen.

Comment: I'm getting tag value from last updating cat_id only..I tried with mvc..but it didn't work

Comment: @user3743552 Not really. Unfortunately, it's a little hard to diagnose this, just looking at the code samples. I'd have to step through these two routines in the debugger, stepping through both routines, one line at a time, to figure out where it's going awry. I'd first double check the `tag` values for the various image views (when you're adding, you're using `[sender tag]-1`, and I'm unclear as to that intent). You're also logging various values as you go along, but its unclear to me whether you're getting the wrong `tag` value or whether there's something else going on.

Comment: cat_id=1 containing images tag of 0,1,2,3 in the screen and cat_id=2 containing images tag of 0,1,2,3. But if i delete the cat_id=1 tag 0 image it deleting cat_id=2 tag 0. because cat_id=2 tag 0 is updated in the screen last

Comment: the tag value & sku value is storing proper...but i'm not getting proper cat_id value while deleting because of last updating value getting

Comment: So that, i used mvc ObjectAddedToScreen

Comment: the tag value is correct...but the cat_id is not updating proper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56126/discussion-between-rob-and-user3743552).